# OpenFileDialog in SAP B1 Add-On C#

Tags: c#, add-on, sapb1

I am working on `SAP B1` Add-On using C#. When I call `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` this exception is thrown:

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode
>   before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has
>   STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
I added `[STAThread]` before the `Main` method but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I Found the solution i added a new thread and it works fine, Here is the code

```
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();


            DialogResult dr = openFileDialog.ShowDialog(new Form());
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
                this.EditText0.Value = fileName;
                SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(fileName);
            }
        });          // Kick off a new thread
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
```

Comment: FYI: This still works with SAPBusinessOneSDK.dll , SAP B1 9.30.180 and Visual Studio 2019.