# How to open PrintDialog stathread multiple times

Tags: c#, add-on, sapb1

I am working on SAP B1 add-on and try to make it possible to select printername from PrintDialog. Because of this error:

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made.
> Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

I made a version of this solution for OpenFileDialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553212

```
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    using (var printerDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog())
    {
        var dr = printerDialog.ShowDialog(new System.Windows.Forms.Form());
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var printer = printerDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
            var cel = matrix.Columns.Item(colUID).Cells.Item(row).Specific;
            ((EditText)cel).String = printer;
        }
    }
});

// Kick off a new thread
t.IsBackground = true;
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

But for code works only 1 time. Second time program breaks on the following line, without error.

```
var dr = printerDialog.ShowDialog(new System.Windows.Forms.Form());
```

After restarting application is works again 1 time.

Comment: Two basic rules for an STA thread: never block and run a dispatcher loop.  Not observing those rules causes deadlock.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend your proposed solution.

I'm not familiar with SAP B1, but in general an application should only have a single UI thread. So the correct solution should be to show the print dialog on the UI thread, if you are on a background thread, see [how should I update the UI from a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread).

If this is not possible for some reason I would suggest creating a single extra UI thread that is kept alive for the duration of the application. I.e. start a thread that creates a hidden window that is never closed, whenever you need to show a printer dialog you can call `.Invoke` on that window object to do whatever you need to do. But having multiple UI threads can make your program difficult to reason about, and may cause odd UI bugs, so I would only do this as a last resort.

If your application do not have any UI thread at all you should be able to use the same hidden-window trick. But it seem rather odd to show a printer UI from a non-UI application.